# Jython - How to get the path of the executed script

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I've found many answer about the python way but what I found isn't working with jython.

I'm running a jython script using the WebSphere interpreter wsadmin -lang jython -f /path/to/script

I'd like to know the path of the script im running.
This script if versionned and can be checked out anywhere so I need to reliably know where the script is being executed from.

Thanx to everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere doesn't make this easy.  And I've yet to find a way to do this when using Sun's JVM running WebSphere on Solaris.  However, you may be able to figure out the script name using the environment when running WebSphere on Linux, Aix and possibly others OSes.  On these platforms, IBM's JVM sets the environment variable IBM_JAVA_COMMAND_LINE.  You can parse it to get the '-f' argument passed to wsadmin.sh  Dave Brand has code to do this on his blog.  See fix #6 in his [ibmfixes.py](http://dbrand666.wordpress.com/ibmfixes-py/) script.

Comment: Thanx I looked it up and it helped a lot. For the sake of not having to follow many links that might not exist anymore in the future here is what I did. import os print os.environement.get('IBM_JAVA_COMMAND_LINE') this gave me the whole JVM argument line but it also gave me the -f option passed to wsadmin.sh which contains the path to my script.